# Stopping users from using the "newitem" and "edititem" forms

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have a series of pages that use the javascript object model to interact with information stored in lists (this supports sort of an application behaviour but not quite, but I can't complain it's the only thing I get to use to fufill a requirement in my organization), if users interact directly with the lists, the information stored in the lists get compromised because of the way I've made this "application", is there a way to stop users from using these forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can [hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.hidden.aspx) those lists or you can grant *Read* permission for users on those list. Note that if you grant *Read* permission on list user can't add or edit list items and in your application you can't do add or edit actions with user credentials so you have to user something like `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)

Also you can edit NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx using SharePoint Designer and delete *ListFormWebPart*, in this case no one (including SystemAccount!) can use NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx

Comment: you can't remove ListFormWebPart from edit & new pages

Comment: changing permissions is a right way.